# Moving my current iCloud+ storage plan to my Wife's Family Sharing plan

Tags: icloud, sharing

I currently have 50GB iCloud+ storage plan. Recently my wife upgraded her own plan to 200GB Family Sharing plan. I am now invited by her. However, before I start using Family Sharing plan, want to ensure my Content (photos/files etc.) in my current 50GB plan gets moved to the Family Share when I switch. What do I need to do? Or the content gets moved automatically when I accept "Use Family Storage" plan? Question is only about the content... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The 50GB you have and the 200GB she has are not specific storage areas, they're just quotas.

When you join her Family, you will automatically receive any shared quotas from the Family. You will NOT lose your paid subscription at first, however. You must cancel that manually. You can wait to cancel it until you've joined the family.

You do not need to do anything to move your data around.